# Why aggregation function pyspark.sql.functions.collect_list() adds local timezone offset on display?

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I run the following code in a pyspark shell session. Running collect_list() after a groupBy, changes how timestamps are displayed (a UTC+02:00 offset is added, probably because this is the local offset at Greece where the code is run). Although the display is problematic, the timestamp under the hood remains unchanged. This can be observed either by adding a column with the actual unix timestamps or by reverting the dataframe to its initial shape through using pyspark.sql.functions.explode(). Is this a bug?

```
import datetime
import os
from pyspark.sql import functions, types, udf

# configure utc timezone
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.session.timeZone", "UTC")
os.environ['TZ']
time.tzset()

# create DataFrame
date_time = datetime.datetime(year = 2019, month=1, day=1, hour=12)
data = [(1, date_time), (1, date_time)]
schema = types.StructType([types.StructField("id", types.IntegerType(), False), types.StructField("time", types.TimestampType(), False)])
df_test = spark.createDataFrame(data, schema)

df_test.show()
+---+-------------------+
| id|               time|
+---+-------------------+
|  1|2019-01-01 12:00:00|
|  1|2019-01-01 12:00:00|
+---+-------------------+

# GroupBy and collect_list
df_test1 = df_test.groupBy("id").agg(functions.collect_list("time"))
df_test1.show(1, False)
+---+----------------------------------------------+
|id |collect_list(time)                            |
+---+----------------------------------------------+
|1  |[2019-01-01 14:00:00.0, 2019-01-01 14:00:00.0]|
+---+----------------------------------------------+

# add column with unix timestamps
to_timestamp = functions.udf(lambda x : [value.timestamp() for value in x], types.ArrayType(types.FloatType()))
df_test1.withColumn("unix_timestamp",to_timestamp(functions.col("collect_list(time)")))
df_test1.show(1, False)
+---+----------------------------------------------+----------------------------+
|id |collect_list(time)                            |unix_timestamp              |
+---+----------------------------------------------+----------------------------+
|1  |[2019-01-01 14:00:00.0, 2019-01-01 14:00:00.0]|[1.54634394E9, 1.54634394E9]|
+---+----------------------------------------------+----------------------------+

# explode list to distinct rows
df_test1.groupBy("id").agg(functions.collect_list("time")).withColumn("test", functions.explode(functions.col("collect_list(time)"))).show(2, False)
+---+----------------------------------------------+-------------------+
|id |collect_list(time)                            |test               |
+---+----------------------------------------------+-------------------+
|1  |[2019-01-01 14:00:00.0, 2019-01-01 14:00:00.0]|2019-01-01 12:00:00|
|1  |[2019-01-01 14:00:00.0, 2019-01-01 14:00:00.0]|2019-01-01 12:00:00|
+---+----------------------------------------------+-------------------+
```

ps. 1.54634394E9 == 2019-01-01 12:00:00, which is the correct UTC timestamp

Comment: In Spark v2.3.2 and Python 2.7 I don't have the same result (i.e. `collect_list(time)` keeps `12:00:00`) and in your function `to_timestamp` I have `value.timestamp()` fails because `AttributeError: 'datetime.datetime' object has no attribute 'timestamp'`.
What is your Spark version ?

Comment: Spark v2.2.1, Python 3.7

Answer (score 0):

For me the code above works, but does not convert the time as in your case.
Maybe check what is your session time zone (and, optionally, set it to some tz):

```
spark.conf.get('spark.sql.session.timeZone')
```

In general TimestampType in pyspark is not tz aware like in Pandas rather it passes long ints and displays them according to your machine's local time zone (by default).

Comment: That's the weird thing. At the begining, I set `spark.conf.set('spark.sql.session.timeZone', 'UTC')`. But in any case, if it displays all timestamps at local timezone, shouldn't it do it in any case? Why only when it is a list of timestamps?